# Devanagari typing

Tags: keyboard, tablet, localization

I want to buy a tablet basically for Marathi or Hindi document typing. Which tablet supports it? Will it be possible for me to type in Marathi or Hindi on Samsung Galaxy Tab or Sony Tab with Honeycomb, either with built-in support or an external app?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of alternative on-screen virtual Keyboard replacement apps on Android Market that support [Hindi](https://market.android.com/search?q=Marathi%20keyboard) and [Marathi](https://market.android.com/search?q=Marathi%20keyboard) languages.  Most should work on all recent Android OS version (2.2 and above.)

Comment: They don't work if Hindi and Marathi fonts aren't available.. And, it's impossible with 2.2.